# Rewrite GET parameters in URL NGINX

Tags: nginx

I would like to get

```
http://example.com/?page=main
```

to

```
http://example.com/main
```

Whenever I use a `rewrite` it'll just download the PHP script directly from my webserver.

Here is what I am using:

```
rewrite ^/(\w+)$ /index.php?page=$1 break;
rewrite ^/(\w+)+\/$ /index.php?page=$1 break;
```

EDIT: Full Configuration for block.

```
server {
    listen 80;

    root /var/www/csgodouble;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name csgovulture.com;
    charset   utf-8;

    gzip on;
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";
    gzip_comp_level 6;
    gzip_min_length 1100;
    gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_types
        text/plain
        text/css
        text/js
        text/xml
        text/javascript
        application/javascript
        application/x-javascript
        application/json
        application/xml
        application/xml+rss;

    location / {
        rewrite ^/(\w+)$ /index.php?page=$1 break;
        rewrite ^/(\w+)+\/$ /index.php?page=$1 break;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri /index.php =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~* \.(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|cur|gz|svg|svgz|mp4|ogg|ogv|webm|htc|svg|woff|woff2|ttf)$ {
      expires 1M;
      access_log off;
      add_header Cache-Control "public";
    }

    location ~* \.(?:css|js)$ {
      expires 7d;
      access_log off;
      add_header Cache-Control "public";
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny  all;
    }

}
```

Comment: Please show your complete nginx configuration for the virtual server.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen Done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `break` in your rewrite rules which prohibits processing of the request by any other locations, so your `location ~ \.php$` is skipped.

Comment: This fixed the issue.